# Deriving conditions on coefficients of polynomial of order 3

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a polynomial of order 3: $z^3+p z^2+q z+12$ my problem is to derive conditions on $p$ and $q$ whenever this polynomial is stable(I.e. all $Re z_j \lt 0$ for all roots $z_j$) So I know the method of complex analysis (argument principle). So we have a boundary of halve circle on the left side of complex plane of some big radius $R$ plus so by argument principle $N_{D_R}(p)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}*\Delta Arg(p)$ where $N_{D_R}$ is an amount of zeros in this half circle We can compute $\Delta Arg(p)$ on half circle it’s $\pi n+ o(1)$ when $R\to\infty$ and where $n$ is order of our polynomial after that we must compute $\Delta Arg(p)$ on line segment $i t$ where $t \in [-R;R]$ now we construct Mikhailov hodograph - $p(i t)$ we do it by constructing the graphs of $Re p(it)$ and $Im p(it)$ separately and then we construct the hodograph (graph where $x$-axis is $Re p(it)$ and $y$ is $Im p(it)$) then we calculate $\Delta Arg$ of this. So I have the problem with last step, I can’t analyze it correctly. So I need to $\Delta Arg$ of this hodograph to be $3 \pi$ In order to have roots in left side of plane. But I can’t see the conditions to satisfy this answer

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StablePolynomial.html says $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is stable if and only if $a>0$, $b>0$, and $ab>c>0$.

Comment: Had a look at that link?

Comment: Yea, thank you!

Comment: If it settles your question, you could write up a summary and post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.